# how to save address and username details in AKV secret?

Tags: azure

How would a common secret that hold the details of a DB address, username and password would look like in Azure Key Vault?
Would all these details be found in the secret's value?
As JSON? (what is the common content type)

I tried placing them in the value - as it is a string everything goes. I just didntsee ANY examples of such secrets and were wondering if i am missing something...

Comment: It would be great if you provide more details like what you have tried. show us your code.

Comment: I think how to format such complex values is up to you no? You could use a DB connection string format or you could use JSON. Both would work. There are other ways as well and I don't think any of them is more "right" than others.